# Is there a way to perform step-up 2FA with OAuth without requiring the password again?

Tags: oauth, multi-factor-authentication

I have an existing web site that uses OAuth for authentication (authorization code flow). The user enters user name and password during initial signon and *may* prompt for 2FA depending on analysis of the user's device signature and other risk factors. This works fine as it is.

Now I have been asked to add step-up authentication to this site. With step-up authentication, certain high-risk features require a 2FA challenge to be answered.

As I understand it, a step-up authentication challenge can be accomplished by sending the browser back to the authorization endpoint, providing an `acr_values` of "urn:okta:loa:2fa". The problem is that this value tells the authorization server that I am requesting "any two factors." But I don't want any two factors. They have already authenticated with a password at this point. I want only the second factor (in this case, OOB OTP) to be presented and answered, under the assumption that the password was already correctly provided earlier.

Is there a way to tell the auth server that I *only* want the second factor, and not the first?

To complicate matters, it's likely that this step-up event will occur after the original token has already passed its expiration. So I can't reliably leverage the existing IDP session.